# different static linking ways of gcc cause different compilation results

Tags: c, gcc, linker, undefined-reference, msgpack

I use msgpack-c 1.0.0, when I compile the following program it failed:

```
#include <msgpack.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    /* creates buffer and serializer instance. */
    msgpack_sbuffer* buffer = msgpack_sbuffer_new();
    msgpack_packer* pk = msgpack_packer_new(buffer, msgpack_sbuffer_write);

    int j;

    for(j = 0; j<23; j++) {
        /* NB: the buffer needs to be cleared on each iteration */
        msgpack_sbuffer_clear(buffer);

        /* serializes ["Hello", "MessagePack"]. */
        msgpack_pack_array(pk, 3);
        msgpack_pack_str(pk, 5);
        msgpack_pack_str_body(pk, "Hello", 5);
        msgpack_pack_str(pk, 11);
        msgpack_pack_str_body(pk, "MessagePack", 11);
        msgpack_pack_int(pk, j);

        /* deserialize the buffer into msgpack_object instance. */
        /* deserialized object is valid during the msgpack_zone instance alive. */
        msgpack_zone mempool;
        msgpack_zone_init(&mempool, 2048);

        msgpack_object deserialized;
        msgpack_unpack(buffer->data, buffer->size, NULL, &mempool, &deserialized);

        /* print the deserialized object. */
        msgpack_object_print(stdout, deserialized);
        puts("");

        msgpack_zone_destroy(&mempool);
    }

    /* cleaninstrong textg */
    msgpack_sbuffer_free(buffer);
    msgpack_packer_free(pk);
}
```

the output is:

```
[biao.zhang@ip-10-18-0-42 ~]$ gcc b.c -Icustom_apps/include/ -L/home/biao.zhang/custom_apps/lib/libmsgpack.a
/tmp/ccZKJsdv.o: In function `main':
b.c:(.text+0x685): undefined reference to `msgpack_zone_init'
b.c:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `msgpack_unpack'
b.c:(.text+0x6d8): undefined reference to `msgpack_object_print'
b.c:(.text+0x6ee): undefined reference to `msgpack_zone_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but when I static link the same library with a different way it can compile successfully and run successfully:

```
[biao.zhang@ip-10-18-0-42 ~]$ gcc b.c -Icustom_apps/include/ -Lcustom_apps/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lmsgpack -Wl,-Bdynamic
[biao.zhang@ip-10-18-0-42 ~]$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff892c5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fef6c221000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fef6c5ef000)
```

Are there any differences between the two ways of static linking? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `gcc`

- `-L` option is to provide the *path to the library*.

  (Your first case, it does not actually *link* with the library. Hence, undefined reference(s)).
- `-l` option is to *provide the name of the library*

  (Your second case, it actually *links* with the specified library)

Further read: Online gcc help manual [for `-l`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) and [for `-L`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)

Comment: @biaozhang as i mentioned, only providing `-L` does not _include_ the library. You need to use `-l` to link with the library. In your first case, `-l` is not there.

Comment: thank you so much.  I forgot  the right way to specify static library.  In fact the following command also works well:  gcc b.c -Icustom_apps/include/ custom_apps/lib/libmsgpack.a